# Getting error while trying to loosely couple node-template to frame support

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, frame

I am trying to couple substrate node-template to frame support in order to use trait currency.
Link to [github](https://github.com/sky-vibhu/customised-pallet) link

Error -

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/data/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/data/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-55554732df6f82a1/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/data/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.65.0-nightly (02654a084 2022-08-30)


  --- stderr
     Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/data/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  warning: unused import: `frame_support::traits::Currency`
   --> /data/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:9:5
    |
  9 | use frame_support::traits::Currency;
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `u128: Currency<AccountId32>` is not satisfied
     --> /data/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:272:19
      |
  272 |      type Currency = Balance;
      |                      ^^^^^^^ the trait `Currency<AccountId32>` is not implemented for `u128`
      |
      = help: the trait `Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>` is implemented for `pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>`
  note: required by a bound in `pallet_template::Config::Currency`
     --> /data/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:36:18
      |
  36  |         type Currency: Currency<Self::AccountId>;
      |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_template::Config::Currency`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
  warning: `node-template-runtime` (lib) generated 1 warning
  error: could not compile `node-template-runtime` due to previous error; 1 warning
```

emitted`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to write `type Currency = Balances`, not `Balance`.
While `Balances` is an instance of `pallet_balances`, `Balance` is just an alias for `u128`. It's the former that implements the `Currency` trait, not the latter.

Comment: Thanks it worked.